# how to zip files by group which is uncertain substring in filenames, using DOS batch script

Tags: batch-file, substring, dos, findstr

I have a bunch of DOS files in a folder that I want to zip by group. The filenames are coded like this:

```
devXXXXdbt01.log

qasXXXXwb01.log

devYYYap01.log

qasYYYdb02.log
```

the first 3 letters are either dev or qas
the following `3-5` letters (**XXXX** or **YYY**) are dynamic group name that I want to use as zip file name
the following 2 letters (db, wb, ap) are one of the 3: db, wb, or ap
the following optional letter t means it's temporary file. in some case the filename does not have the letter t
the last 2 digits are serial number

so I'd like to create zip file ***XXXX.zip*** that contains files like the first 2, zip file ***YYY.zip*** that contains files like the last 2.

How can I script a DOS batch to do it automatically, without hard coding group names?

Comment: which zip program do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET sourcedir=c:\sourcedir
SET destdir=u:
PUSHD "%sourcedir%"
FOR /f %%i IN ('dir /b /a-d dev*.* qas*.*') DO CALL :zipme %%i
popd
GOTO :EOF

:zipme
SET destzip=%~n1
SET "num="
SET /a num=1%destzip:~-2% 2>nul
IF NOT DEFINED num ECHO(reject %1&GOTO :EOF 
FOR %%g IN (db wb ap) DO (
 IF /i %%g==%destzip:~-4,2% SET destzip=%destzip:~3,-4%&GOTO zipthis
 IF /i %%gt==%destzip:~-5,3% SET destzip=%destzip:~3,-5%&GOTO zipthis
)
ECHO(reject %1
GOTO :EOF
:zipthis
ECHO wzzip -a "%destdir%\%destzip%" %1
GOTO :eof
```

Example source directory:

```
abcxxxdb01.log
devxxxdb01.log
devxxxdb02.log
devxxxdbt03.log
devxxxdbt0x.log
devxxxdbtx1.log
devyyyydbt03.log
devzzzzzap03.log
devzzzzzapt99.log
devzzzzzapt999.log
devzzzzzdb03.log
devzzzzzdbt03.log
devzzzzzjq03.log
devzzzzzwb03.log
devzzzzzxy03.log
qasxxxdb01.log
qasxxxdb02.log
qasxxxdbt03.log
qasxxxdbt0x.log
qasxxxdbtx1.log
qasyyyydbt03.log
qaszzzzzap03.log
qaszzzzzapt99.log
qaszzzzzapt999.log
qaszzzzzdb03.log
qaszzzzzdbt03.log
qaszzzzzjq03.log
qaszzzzzwb03.log
qaszzzzzxy03.log
zxzxxxdb01.log
```

Run results:

```
wzzip -a "u:\xxx" devxxxdb01.log
wzzip -a "u:\xxx" devxxxdb02.log
wzzip -a "u:\xxx" devxxxdbt03.log
reject devxxxdbt0x.log
reject devxxxdbtx1.log
wzzip -a "u:\yyyy" devyyyydbt03.log
wzzip -a "u:\zzzzz" devzzzzzap03.log
wzzip -a "u:\zzzzz" devzzzzzapt99.log
reject devzzzzzapt999.log
wzzip -a "u:\zzzzz" devzzzzzdb03.log
wzzip -a "u:\zzzzz" devzzzzzdbt03.log
reject devzzzzzjq03.log
wzzip -a "u:\zzzzz" devzzzzzwb03.log
reject devzzzzzxy03.log
wzzip -a "u:\xxx" qasxxxdb01.log
wzzip -a "u:\xxx" qasxxxdb02.log
wzzip -a "u:\xxx" qasxxxdbt03.log
reject qasxxxdbt0x.log
reject qasxxxdbtx1.log
wzzip -a "u:\yyyy" qasyyyydbt03.log
wzzip -a "u:\zzzzz" qaszzzzzap03.log
wzzip -a "u:\zzzzz" qaszzzzzapt99.log
reject qaszzzzzapt999.log
wzzip -a "u:\zzzzz" qaszzzzzdb03.log
wzzip -a "u:\zzzzz" qaszzzzzdbt03.log
reject qaszzzzzjq03.log
wzzip -a "u:\zzzzz" qaszzzzzwb03.log
reject qaszzzzzxy03.log
```

All you essentially need to do is set your source and destination directorynames.

The routine `:zipme` is `call`ed  passing each filename from the source directory that matches the filemasks specified. The name part alone is assigned to `destzip` and `num` first deleted and then assigned to 100+the last 2 characters of the name. If the result is not a number, `nun` remains unassigned (the `2>nul` suppresses the error) and the filename rejected (the display is optional, of course.)

Next, the three target character combinations are matched against the string from the fourth-last character for two characters, and again with `t` appended to the fifth-last for 3 characters. Any match causes a transfer to `ZIPTHIS` and  if none match, then the reject is (optionally) reported.

From there, it's simply a matter of invoking your zip program - I've just `ECHO`ed the `WZZIP` command-line.